# Get raw json string in Spring MVC Rest

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, gson

Im have @RestController and this method. how can I get any json and then select the handler depending on the method and pass it there for processing
PS. I use GSON instead of JACKSON

[image: Method]

Answer (score 1):

You can use @RequestBody in your method and take a String parameter:

```
public AbstractJsonResponse(@PaqthVariable String method, @RequestBody String json) {
  ...
}
```

See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html

Mainly the part that says:

> > Annotation indicating a method parameter should be bound to the body of the web request